# Classes and Scaners

Tags: eclipse, class, methods

I am attempting to write a program that decrements the number of cups still in a dispenser by 1. How can I do this using a constructor? I want to do this using some objects too... And I don't really have much code of my own to share - because I am absolutely at a wall here and was hoping someone could steer me in the right direction?

Comment: What language are you using? Where's your code? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am using the java language and I am at a wall when it comes to using objects and constructs.

Comment: you may want to mention Java and the code in the question, as well as add the Java tag.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like that?

```
public class DecrementStackOverFlow {

private int nOfCups, initNum;

public DecrementStackOverFlow(int num) {
    this.nOfCups = num;     
    this.initNum = num;
}

public int decCups () {
    this.nOfCups = this.nOfCups -1;
    return this.nOfCups;
}
public int getNumOfCup () {
    return this.initNum;
}

public static void main (String [] args) {
    DecrementStackOverFlow decr = new DecrementStackOverFlow(10);

    for (int i=0; i<decr.getNumOfCup(); i++) {
        System.out.println(decr.decCups());
    }
}
```

}